# Can someone show me the steps involved in having Jenkins build automatically from a git repository I don't own

Tags: git, jenkins

For various reasons I would like to build some Github/Gitlab repositories that I don't personally own, so the problem exists that I cannot use the git(lab|hub) hooks, that are built into git(lab|hub), to auto build on push's.  Currently I have them just set up as manual builds but I would like to avoid letting my Jenkins get out of date.  Is there a plugin I should be using for this and if possible could someone post screenshots on how to set this up?

Comment: If you're not concerned about latency and assuming the GitHub repositories are public, then you could have Jenkins poll the repositories.

Comment: Ideally it would be nice that it happens on push but its likely the only way that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to poll the repository: In the section *Build Triggers* enable *Poll SCM* and set a reasonable value like every half hour `H/30 * * * *`

Comment: It wouldn't really be unreasonable to poll even less often.  Thanks I will look into this and give it a checkmark if it seems to work out.

Comment: Seems that this works just fine thank you :)  You've saved me heaps of time.  Sometimes the thirst for knowledge doesn't come with the luxury of time to learn.